# How to get last month records in postgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How to get last month records in postgreSQL ? Please help.

Most probably how can I write the psql query for this?

Note: I have a `created_at` field in my table.

Comment: "psql" is the Postgresql command line client. In your question, does "psql" = "Postgresql"?

Comment: yes it is postgreSQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a scope in the model defined as:

```
scope :in_last_month, where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? ', 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month , 1.month.ago.end_of_month)
```

Or

```
scope :in_last_month, where(:created_at => 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.end_of_month)
```

Then call:

```
 Model.in_last_month
```

similarly you may have scopes for current month, before previous month etc.

Comment: +1 for `.begining_of_month` didn't know I could do that.
However, you can just do this `1.month.ago.beginning_of_month` also your query would get `created_at` last month until first of next month since `BETWEEN` is inclusive so I think it should be `BETWEEN ? AND ?,    1.month.ago.beginning_of_month ,1.month.ago.end_of_month` instead.

Comment: And to make it even more ARel'ish, you could write it as `scope :in_last_month, where(:created_at => 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.. 1.month.ago.end_of_month)`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have `User` model then

```
  date = Date.today >> -1
  User.where("DATE_FORMAT('created_at', '%Y-%m') = ?" date.strftime("%Y-%m"))
```

For postgres

```
  User.where("TO_CHAR('created_at', '%YYYY-%MM') = ?" date.strftime("%Y-%m"))
```

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function date_format(unknown, unknown) does not exist

Comment: @Debadatt:- Check my edited answer it should work for posgres, u should go for the `Muntasim` answer as it uses index while fetching the data.

Comment: @Salil.. yes i found the answer from Muntasim answer also a j03w comment

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass a range:

```
User.where(created_at: Time.now..1.month.ago)
```

You can add this to a class method:

```
def self.created_in_last_month
  where(created_at: Time.now..1.month.ago)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This could also help ..

```
scope :in_last_month, where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? ', 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 1.month.ago.end_of_month.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

as i found the correct query it generates the `created_at BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31'`